# Do Deadeye or Tactical Visor target an invisible Sombra?

Tags: overwatch

There are a few questions already posted about when and if Sombra can be seen with her camouflage active but so far this hasn't been brought up. As of right now there are only these 2 ultimates that directly lock-on to an enemy, but do they still target a Sombra that can't be seen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless she is revealed by something else (being too close, sonic arrows or Infrared Sight) you should be untargettable.

On the other hand, you have to still be careful while being Sombra as damage will reveal you. Getting shot by 76 while he's targetting someone else is still a possibility. After that, you'll be targettable.

Comment: You *should* be untargetable? That's not really convincing though it could just be your wording.

Comment: I'm just uncertain of the behavior of Zarya revealing her location with her shield. I suppose you remain untargettable but you can easily shoot in her direction.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither of them will directly lock onto an invisible Sombra.