# Can Sombra Block Dead-Eye Shots?

Tags: overwatch

A rather handy answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291225/do-deadeye-or-tactical-visor-target-an-invisible-sombra) shows that soldier:76 can still hit an invisible Sombra during his ultimate, however my question is can an ulting McCree hit an invisible sombra? I'm not talking about his ultimate locking onto the Sombra, but if a Sombra is standing in front of a target will it hit her instead of the target, and if so can it deal headshot damage? (if the shot lands on Sombra's head)

Comment: Anything *can* hit an invisible Sombra as long as it isn't a targeted attack an example being Symmetra's primary fire. It's just a matter of luck or maybe skill since she is invisible after all. She doesn't become immune or invincible, just invisible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Dead Eye can hit an invisible Sombra if she is standing in front of a different target, but it can never deal headshot damage.

Comment: Dead Eye shots can also be blocked by any other hero if they are in the way, such as an Orisa or Reinheart.